# Please help me find my error

Tags: linear-algebra, broken-code

When I use variables, errors are encountered. But when I change the variables to constants, I don't have a problem, but I wonder why.

```
a1 = 0.9090;
a2 = 0.0562;
a3 = 0.0134;
x11 = 1.3239462454`*^-6;
x12 = 5.4734307087`*^-10;
x13 = 0.12903890128390;
x14 = -8.285608109`*^-6;
x22 = 0.000020305755046`;
x23 = 0.12907389012839012789;   
x24 = 3.2285466078999995`*^-6;
x33 = 0.000048999092233`;
x34 = 0.12938712893712983;
x44 = 0.00011410481871`;
y11 = 1.8595941661`*^-8;
y12 = 0.921083901273982;
y21 = 0.000016512281559`;
y22 = 0.128937128937127938;
y31 = 00.1387289137981238;
y32 = 0.000016103440960000002`;
y41 = -3.8491391671000005`*^-8;
y42 = 0.2139812903829013;
g11 = 0.000028025007587`;
g12 = 0.19890283901213;
g22 = 0.000011146659096000001`;
X = {{x11, x12, x13, x14}, {x12, x22, x23, x24}, {x13, x23, x33, 
    x34}, {x14, x24, x34, x44}};
Y = {{y11, y12}, {y21, y22}, {y31, y32}, {y41, y42}};
G = {{g11, g12}, {g12, g22}};
Q = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}};
Q1 = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
Q2 = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}};
Q3 = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
Q4 = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}};
A1 = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {a3, 0, 0, 0}, {-a2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -a3, a2}};
A2 = {{-a3, a2}, {0, -a1}, {a1, 0}, {0, 0}};
A3 = {{0, a3, 0, -a1}, {0, -a2, a1, 0}};
Z1 = Dot[(Dot[Q1, X] + Dot[Q2, Transpose[Y]]), Transpose[Q1]] + 
   Dot[(Dot[Q1, Y] + Dot[Q2, G]), Transpose[Q2]];
Z2 = Dot[(Dot[Q1, X] + Dot[Q2, Transpose[Y]]), Transpose[Q3]];
Z3 = Dot[(Dot[A1, X] + Dot[A2, Transpose[Y]]), Transpose[Q1]] + 
   Dot[(Dot[A1, Y] + Dot[A2, G]), Transpose[Q2]];
Z4 = Dot[(Dot[Q1, Y] + Dot[Q2, G]), Q4] + 
   Dot[(Dot[A1, X] + Dot[A2, Transpose[Y]]), Transpose[Q3]];
Z5 = Dot[(Dot[A1, Y] + Dot[A2, G]), Q4];
Z6 = Dot[Q3, X, Transpose[Q1]] + Dot[Q3, Y, Transpose[Q2]];
Z7 = Dot[Q3, X, Transpose[Q3]];
Z8 = Dot[(Dot[Q4, Transpose[Y]] + Dot[A3, X]), Transpose[Q1]] + 
   Dot[(Dot[Q4, G] + Dot[A3, Y]), Transpose[Q2]];
Z9 = Dot[Q3, Y, Q4] + 
   Dot[(Dot[Q4, Transpose[Y]] + Dot[A3, X]), Transpose[Q3]];
Z10 = Dot[(Dot[Q4, G] + Dot[A3, Y]), Q4];
Z11 = Dot[Inverse[Z10], Z6] - 
   Dot[Inverse[Dot[Transpose[Z5], Z5]], Transpose[Z5], Z1];
Z12 = Dot[Inverse[Z10], Z7] - 
  Dot[Inverse[Dot[Transpose[Z5], Z5]], Transpose[Z5], Z2]; Z13 = 
 Dot[Inverse[Z10], Z8] - 
  Dot[Inverse[Dot[Transpose[Z5], Z5]], Transpose[Z5], Z3]; Z14 = 
 Dot[Inverse[Z10], Z9] - 
  Dot[Inverse[Dot[Transpose[Z5], Z5]], Transpose[Z5], Z4];
Z15 = Z1 - Dot[Z5, Inverse[Z10], Z6];
Z16 = Z2 - Dot[Z5, Inverse[Z10], Z7];
Z17 = Z3 - Dot[Z5, Inverse[Z10], Z8];
Z18 = Z4 - Dot[Z5, Inverse[Z10], Z9];
Z19 = Inverse[(Z12 - Dot[Z11, Inverse[Z15], Z16])];
```

I wonder if too many variables are problematic during the calculation, or if the problem arises in the calculation process.

Please Help me.

Comment: If you use `NullSpace` on the symbolic matrix $m = Z_{12}-Z_{11}\cdot Z_{15}^{-1} \cdot Z_{16}$, it returns 2 vectors.  I believe that proves matrix $m$ is singular.  When you put in approximate numbers, you could get round off errors that make your numeric matrix invertible.  But, your numeric matrix is only approximately equal to the symbolic matrix $m$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: And the problem title does not describe the content of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the variable settings there is only one error, in the last line: Mathematica finds `(Z12 - Dot[Z11, Inverse[Z15], Z16])` in symbolic form is singular.  Up to that step the solution is ok.  Currently trying `FullSimplify[penultimateStep]` to see if that helps ... still running.

[image]